# fixing pvalue in MATLAB correlation function

Tags: matlab, correlation, p-value

is it possible to fix the pvalue in the `corr` function in MATLAB?
I would need to find the correlation between 2 vectors for p=0.01

Thanks,
Gabriele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p-values` is used for testing the hypothesis of no correlation and it is actually one of the outputs of the correlation analysis not a parameter to change. by [definition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html):

`Each p-value is the probability of getting a correlation as large as the observed value by random chance, when the true correlation is zero.`

I think what you want to change is actually 'alpha' variable.

`alpha` is a number between 0 and 1 to specify a confidence level of `100*(1 – alpha)%`. Default is `0.05` for `95%` confidence intervals.

Otherwise, you should edit the question and add more details.